# Cannot access iis website by IP

Tags: asp.net, iis, website, ip

I have hosted asp.net mvc3 simplest application on my machine. I specified my IP in config and if i try to enter in address bar "myIP/applicationName" everything works, but it fails from other machine. What can be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your Windows firewall might be blocking port 80 ;)